# zend_date relative time

Tags: zend-framework, zend-date

i want to make stackoverflow timestamps(X minutes ago, etc). How i can make it using zend_date? I found [How to calculate time passed with PHP or Zend_Date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1639892/how-to-calculate-time-passed-with-php-or-zend-date) this realisation, but it uses other library. Are there any different ways?

Answer (score 2):

How about `Zend_Date::subDate()`?

```
$d1 = new Zend_Date();
$d2 = new Zend_Date($old_date);
$diff = $d1->subDate($d2);
```

After you've got the difference, you can check out one of these helpers:

- [Relative time view helper](http://www.zfsnippets.com/snippets/view/id/2)
- [Zend_View_Helper_Relativetime](http://www.zfsnippets.com/snippets/view/id/43)

Answer (score 1):

Even if you don't want the whole Zym framework, you could still add their [`TimeSince` view helper](http://zym.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/library/Zym/View/Helper/TimeSince.php) to your own application.

Answer (score 0):

You can subtract timestamps of two dates to find difference between them in seconds and then use division and modulo to represent it as minutes, days etc.